# fortran 2D array save

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, allocation

I am trying to save and reuse a 2D variable after each run but I am getting some errors like automatic object can't be saved etc.
Here is the subroutine:

```
subroutine dust_sum_test(ngrid,count,dust_in,dust_out)

!Subroutine to accumulate and release dust in timely manner
implicit none
integer,intent(in)::ngrid
integer,intent(in)::count
real,intent(in)::dust_in(ngrid)
real,intent(out)::dust_out(ngrid)

real,save::dmsdust(ngrid,99999) ! dummy local variable
integer::i
if (count.gt.1) then
  dmsdust(:,count)=dmsdust(:,count-1)+dust_in
  dust_out=dmsdust(:,count)
else
dust_out=dust_in
dmsdust(:,count)=0.0
endif

write(*,*)'The current count is = ', count
end subroutine dust_sum_test
```

I need to add current value with previous dmsdust values. Please let me know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 8):

[Ross explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33326427) the source of the error, and offers some sensible other approaches.  An additional one, not mentioned in that answer, follows.  I don't say it's better, or recommend it, though.

While automatic objects cannot have the `save` attribute, an allocatable array may.  A saved local allocatable object retains its allocation status and, if allocated, its shape (if an array) and value.

```
real, allocatable, save :: dmsdust(:,:)  ! Initially not allocated
...
! Our first-time initialization and subsequent consistency check follows
if (.not.allocated(dmsdust)) then
  allocate(dmsdust(ngrid,99999), source=0.)
else
  if (size(dmsdust,1).ne.ngrid) error stop ! or some other handling
end if
```

Answer (score 7):

The error is correct - you can't save an automatic array. The reason for this *specific* error is:

`dmsdust` is formed 'automatically' each time `dust_sum_test` executes with a size based on the input to `dmsdust`. So `dmsdust` is an automatic array.
Your subroutine `dust_sum_test` takes in the value of `ngrid` each time it runs, but there's no guarentee that `ngrid` will be the same each time. What if the first time it's run `ngrid` is 1 and the second time `ngrid` is 2? How could `dmsdust` be saved and also change shape? So the compiler doesn't let you make this mistake.

The real solution to your problem is to change your approach. Your question doesn't say *why* you need to store the history of `dust`, but I assume you do. However, there is no reason for you to store it in this subroutine! In fact, storing it in the subroutine (as a `save`d value) means it will be hard to access. Instead, I believe there are two other good options.

### Use a Module

Modules are a staple of modern fortran and can store both data and subroutines. You could keep the history of `dust` in this module and access it both in and out of the module. The implementation would look something like:

```
module mymod
   implicit none
   real, allocatable :: dmsdust(:,:)
contains

subroutine init_dmsdust(ngrid)
   integer, intent(IN) :: ngrid
   allocate(dmsdust(ngrid,9999))
end subroutine init_dmsdust

subroutine dust_sum_test(ngrid,count,dust_in,dust_out)
   ! -- all your other code, but now dmsdust is not an automatic array
end subroutine dust_sum_test
end module mymod
```

In this implementation, you must call `init_dmsdust` once at the start to allocate the storage space. Then you use it later in each call to `dmsdust`. You could access `dmsdust` by adding an access subroutine to `mymod` or `use`-ing the variable `dmsdust` from another section of your code.

### Store the history in the calling routine

This solution is simpler but not as extensible or elegant. Instead of giving `dust_sum_test` the job of keeping `dmsdust`, make whatever routine is responsible for calling `dust_sum_test` allocate and pass `dmsdust`. A section of your calling routine would look like:

```
allocate(dmsdust(ngrid,9999))
do count=1,max  ! -- The main loop
   call dust_sum_test(ngrid,count,dust_in,dust_out,dmsdust)
   ! some other stuff
enddo
```

And then the subroutine looks like:

```
subroutine dust_sum_test(ngrid,count,dust_in,dust_out,dmsdust)
   implicit none
   real, intent(INOUT) :: dmsdust(:,:)

   ! -- All the other stuff
end subroutine dust_sum_test
```

This way the calling routine has access to `dmsdust` and it's known to be always the same size.